# HTML Title Comment

Tags: html

Ok so I was doing a very simple program and I found that there's a bug in the comment.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- This starts the html file -->

<head>
  <!-- This is the head  -->

  <title>
    <!-- This states the title for the webpage -->
    Website's title
  </title>

</head>

</html>
```

Instead of showing the title as Website's title it shows the comment.

Comment: What is this "it" which parses this HTML incorrectly?

Comment: I don't see the comment in the snippet, though.

Comment: `<html><!-- This starts the html file -->` — You forgot the Doctype.

Comment: @prgrm Yes, because it doesn't show the title of the website and there's no body tag.

Comment: It actually shows both, the comment **and** "Website's title". I tested with Safari, Chrome and Firefox. And it's very very very unlikely that it is a bug ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug.

See [the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element):

The content model of `<title>` is **Text**.

The `<` sign (unless followed by the rest of an end for the title element) is not interpreted as having any special meaning there.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use comments like that: place above/to the side:

```
<!-- website title -->
<title>This is my title</title>
```

this is the correct way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You put the comment `<!-- This states the title for the webpage -->` between the `<title>` and `</title>` tags, so the comment is considered to be part of the title.

You should remove that comment or put it before the `<title>` tag.